# Running a task in a Flutter app at certain times

Tags: android, ios, swift, flutter, scheduled-tasks

Hello flutter/mobile developers,

I have a particular problem at hand and I need some advice.  I need to create an app that will do a certain task at specific times of the day.  The times will change daily, and it will get the updated times via a REST call at midnight (or at off peak hours).  The task must at the scheduled time no matter what, even after device restart, etc.  I have looked into this extensively and I'm coming away with the feeling that Flutter does not handle a scheduled task well, especially in iOS which can terminate an app for whatever reason.

The options I have looked into are:

1. workmanager (https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager/changelog): This seems the most promising, if not for the minimum frequency of 15 minutes, which is not enough for me.  I would need to check every minute if it is time to do the task.  Is there a way around this limitation?
2. Native solution.  I have very little-to-no experience with native iOS and Android coding so I would not prefer this solution.  But through some research I have seen some examples where a task can be scheduled through this approach.
3. Server side notification.  This seems like a good solution on the surface, and I need advice on this.  The calculation whether it is time to run the task will happen server-side, and a notification (through Firebase, for example) can be sent to the device, which will trigger the task to be run.  Is this even feasible, will the device actually run code when it gets the notification?

So these are my options.  Which doe you think is the most doable?  If someone with more mobile experience than me can help me out I would appreciate it, maybe there is a better solution that the three I have proposed.  Thank you.

Comment: " Is there a way around this limitation?" ... Only if Apple changes their policies.

Comment: I came across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TWJ_rR7K6g) video which goes over some strategies/ patterns for the config behaviour which I think is applicable to more than the name of the video ("Firebase remote config").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The times will change daily, and it will get the updated times via a REST call at midnight (or at off peak hours).

This smells like bad architecture. Why?

- You are DDOS'ing your update server at midnight (if you have many users in the same timezone). You can stagger your HTTP requests by a few seconds to fix this, but this is a band-aid, not a long term solution.
- because you are inverting the dependency: It sounds like timing is the responsibility of the server (hence your clients call it to ask for the latest time). Your clients should not be the ones asking the server for updates, because now your client has 2 jobs: Schedule the schedule updates and also schedule the scheduled task for the user. Making clients ask the server is the wrong *direction*. You should send messages from the server to update the schedule on the device.
- Even if you do poll the server for schedule updates, you should make the mobile app schedule notifications/ alarm at the time you want. Using silent notifications is a known workaround the limitations of background scheduling on iOS. On Android, WorkManager is [not the right library](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/#exact), you should use `AlarmManager`.
- Here is how another StackOverflow thought about using local notifications to solve the problem: [They](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905143/how-to-create-alarm-app-in-flutter-for-ios) used [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications)

### Answering the bullet points

1. On Android, don't use WorkManager, use **AlarmManager** instead, or even better, schedule notifications. Having said there are some manufacturer specific quirks on Android, see the [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) docs:

> Consequently, scheduled notifications may not work when the application is in the background on certain devices (e.g. by Xiaomi, Huawei). If you experience problems like this then this would be the reason why. As it's a restriction imposed by the OS, this is not something that can be resolved by the plugin.

2. Its not necessary to use Native code, notifications is a standard feature.
3. You can keep the polling architecture for now since its simpler (but dirtier). Even if you would so the server side architecture, I would send messages from server to client to **only update** the client side schedule, **not to trigger work/ user alerts**, otherwise you are making your application dependent on the internet when it doesn't sound like the internet is required (unlike social media notifications). This would lead to bad user experience for badly connected devices.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response.  Can you add the link to the stackoverflow question that used flutter_local_notifications?

Comment: Oh sorry, I thought I added it. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61905143/how-to-create-alarm-app-in-flutter-for-ios) it is

Comment: Hi Ben, I have a question about flutter_local_notifications.  This plugin looks like it will just show a notification at the scheduled time.  But is there a way to run some other task at the scheduled time?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought you could actually use notifications to trigger background work, but this is not possible. If you use FCM, them you can send a "data message" to trigger background work, but that is complicated and makes your app rely on the internet as stated before. So finally, I found this, I think it would be useful to schedule work: https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

Comment: I guess the limitation is you can't schedule an exact time, as mentioned before with that. So I guess on Android you can use [android_alarm_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/android_alarm_manager). I'll have a look at how it can be done on iOS

Comment: Could you use ["initial delay"](https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager#initial-delay) to schedule the task from the current time?: `Workmanager.registerOneOffTask`

Answer (score 0):

You can send Data Notifications through Firebase, and handle them with the `onBackgroundMessage` callback. See here: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage#background-messages

```dart
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");
}

void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

From the documentation (Android/Apple):

> 1. It must not be an anonymous function.
> 2. It must be a top-level function (e.g. not a class method which requires initialization).